# Output arguments in sorted order

Tags: bash, sorting

I need to write a bash script that prints out its command line arguments in sorted order, one per line.

I wrote this script and it works fine, but is there any other way? Especially without outputting it to a file and sorting.

```
#!/bin/bash

for var in $*
do
    echo $var >> file
done

sort file
rm file
```

Test run of the program:

```
$ script hello  goodbye zzz aa
aa
goodbye
hello
zzz
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

for var in "$@"; do
    echo "$var"
done | sort
```

You want to use `$@` in quotes (instead of `$*`) to accommodate arguments with spaces, such as

```
script hello "goodbye, cruel world"
```

The pipe gets rid of the need for a temporary file.

Comment: `$var` also needs quotes, else word splitting and pathname expansion will be attempted after the variable has been expanded.

Comment: Good point, I was only thinking of the line being passed whole to sort.

Comment: @chepner, How about sorting the following arguments based on the first argument which determines the size of the input?

Comment: You can simply discard the first argument by adding a call to `shift` prior to the for loop.

Answer (score 17):

You can pipe the for-loop to sort, or just do

```
printf '%s\n' "$@" | sort
```

Comment: I always forget about the implicit loop provided by `printf`.